# UWP app with an empty App.g.cs file, as a result, no InitializeComponent method defined

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am creating a UWP app with visual studio 2015, but ,suddenly, when I am getting an error, which is as following

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'App' does not contain a definition for
>   'InitializeComponent' and no extension method 'InitializeComponent'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'App' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   WaitOrLeave C:\Users\Hatim Makki\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WaitOrLeave\WaitOrLeave\App.xaml.cs 35  Active

but when I investigated the issue, I found that the file App.gs.c is empty

so, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe your `App.xaml` has a syntax typo. Does it compile without errors? Did you restart VS?

Comment: No, the file App.xaml is OK.

Comment: ZoolWay, actually i found a syntax typo in another xaml page. thank you so much.